# How Pakistan will qualify for semi finals in world cup 2019?

Tags: cricket, cricket-world-cup, qualifying

The Current Standings for the world cup 2019 are as follows:

| Team | Played | Won | Lost | No Result | NRR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | 8 | 7 | 1 | 0 | +1.000 |
| India | 7 | 5 | 1 | 1 | +0.854 |
| New Zealand | 8 | 5 | 2 | 1 | +0.572 |
| England | 8 | 5 | 3 | 0 | +1.000 |
| Pakistan | 8 | 4 | 3 | 1 | -0.792 |
| Sri Lanka | 8 | 3 | 3 | 2 | -0.934 |
| Bangladesh | 7 | 3 | 3 | 1 | -0.133 |
| South Africa | 8 | 2 | 5 | 1 | -0.080 |
| West Indies | 8 | 1 | 6 | 1 | -0.335 |
| Afghanistan | 8 | 0 | 8 | 0 | -1.418 |

I simply want to know that how Pakistan could qualify for semi-finals the after India is defeated by England.

[image]

But I can not understand the criteria through which a team is ranked in standings. According to me the Points are used to rank the team and when Points of two teams are same then they use Net Run Rate (NRR). If we consider this criteria then New-Zealand has to win against England (ODI 41 of 48) so points of England remain at 10 and after that Pakistan has to defeat Bangladesh to get 11 points (ODI 43 of 48). In this case Pakistan will qualify.

But my given criteria conflicts with the [criteria of Geo Sports](https://www.geo.tv/latest/241918-how-can-pakistan-team-reach-the-semifinal-interesting-situation-on-points-table) which is a Sports channel in Pakistan. It says:

> Pakistan will have to defeat Bangladesh on July 5 to qualify for the semi-finals and also have to rely on the result of the match between England and New Zealand.

If England beat New Zealand and Pakistan beat Bangladesh, then the green shirts will qualify for the semi-finals. If that does not happen and Pakistan and England both manage to win their last matches, then the decision to reach the semifinal between New Zealand and Pakistan will be on run rate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Pakistan lose to Bangladesh, they have 9 points, which is  less than the top four teams. They cannot make the semifinals this way.

If Pakistan draws with Bangladesh, they require England's run rate to drop below their own, which requires an extremely large loss to New Zealand. Pakistan's net run rate or NRR would stay the same in case of a drawn match, so England's NRR must drop by 1.8, meaning New Zealand must score runs almost three times faster than England in that match.

If Pakistan beats Bangladesh, either

- England and New Zealand draw, so Pakistan can overtake England with a significant gain in their own NRR, accounting for the drop in England's NRR, due to having 11 points each
- England beats New Zealand, so Pakistan can overtake New Zealand with a significant gain in their own NRR, accounting for the drop in New Zealand's NRR, due to having 11 points each
- New Zealand beats England, so Pakistan overtakes England directly, due to having 11 points over England's 10